# Resize div on resizing window

Tags: html, css

I built an HTML/CSS footer for a site. But when I resize the screen, the footer doesn't resize and I can only see a clipped footer. I'd like the footer div to resize so I can see all the text at any time. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
/* Footer Style */
#footer-background {
 position: fixed;
 height: 30px;
 left: 0%;
 bottom: 0%;
 z-index: 50;
 width: 100%;
 background: #000000;
 opacity: 0.80;
}
#footer-box{
 width: 95%;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
#footer-box h2{
 margin-top: 0;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #A9A9A9;
}
#footer-box a{
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
 color: #A9A9A9;
}
#footer-box a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!-- Footer bar -->
<div id="footer-background">
 <div id="footer-box">
  <h2>
  <a href="/abc/">Title 1</a> |
  <a href="/abc/">Title 2</a> |
  <a href="/abc/">Title 3</a> |
  <a href="/abc/">Title 4</a> |
  <a href="/abc/">Title 5</a> |
  <a href="/abc/">Title 6</a> |
  <a href="/abc/">Title 7</a> |
  <a href="/abc/">Title 8</a>
  </h2>   
 </div>
</div>
<!--/ Footer bar -->
```

Comment: You need to remove the fixed height (`height: 30px;`). This value won't magically adjust it's self as the text wraps.

Comment: This seems to be resizing on latest chrome browser. Is this a browser specific issue?

Comment: @turnip - I modified the height from 30px to 10% and it works. But the height of the footer was too much for me - leaving lot of blank space at bottom. Then I set it to 5% but that doesn't work on resizing. I want the height to be as much as the text height and it adjusts on resizing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on suggestions from folks above, I am pasting the answer here for reference to others who would like to see a working solution!

```css
.footer-box{
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #000000;
 font-size: 11px;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0.8;
 z-index: 50;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
.footer-box h2{
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #A9A9A9;
}
.footer-box a{
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
 color: #A9A9A9;
}
.footer-box a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-box">
 <h2>
 <a href="/weddings/">Weddings</a> |
 <a href="/cityhall/">City Hall</a> |
 <a href="/engagements/">Engagements</a> |
 <a href="/barmitzvah/">Bar Mitzvah,Quinceanera</a> |
 <a href="/birthdays/">Birthdays</a> |
 <a href="/maternity/">Maternity</a> |
 <a href="/portraits/">Portraits</a>
 </h2>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to address some points here :
(1) "height" property

```
#footer-background {
    position: fixed;
    height: 30px;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.80;
}
```

In above piece of code you added height:30px; meaning, you are restricting this element to grow if content wrap around. You can use padding: 20px; or whatever size you want so that when you scale down the screen size, content will wrap inside the element.
(2) h2 has pre-defined css property

```
#footer-box h2{
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #A9A9A9;
}
```

h2 element has predefined margins. instead of just removing margin-top, try to remove margins from all around h2. i.e margin:0;
I hope this will help you understanding the point.

Comment: Thanks for answer and the explanation. It works with setting height in % for the div and margin to 0 for the h2.

Answer (score 0):

As @turnip pointed out your div has a fixed height, that means that you can't see the rest of the items because they overflow the container.

Try removing `height: 30px;`. To achieve this height for wide enough screen you simply need to add `margin-bottom: 0;` for `h2` tag.

P.S. Consider using classes instead of ids to style your layout, the have much less specificity and are considered a good practice to use.

P.P.S. Why are you using an `h2` for a list of links, how about `ul` and `li`?

Comment: I'm a UI novice so this is what I came up with. But I can try out ul and li as next steps and also having the CSS uses classes instead of id's. I mentioned in my top comment about changing height from px to % but that has it's own issues. Any further thoughts?

Comment: My answer already covers the extra space at the bottom, using percent values will not work altogether.