# Resizing multiple divs on resizing window

Tags: html, css

I asked a question some days ago about resizing a div when resizing the browser so that it looks good on desktop and on mobile devices. But now I have an extended problem to the same. I have 2 divs one below the other and the bottom footer div resizes on resizing the browser. The working solution can be found here in my previous post: [Resize div on resizing window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303350/resize-div-on-resizing-window)

But in the problem here, I added another div on top of it. On resizing the browser window, the divs don't stack on top of one another. They work fine on a full window on a desktop. Would appreciate any suggestions that you may have or if you'd like to modify the sample code - that would be great!

```css
.info-banner {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.info-banner a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info-banner a:hover {
  color: #aaa;
}

.footer-box {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 50;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.footer-box h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #A9A9A9;
}

.footer-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #A9A9A9;
}

.footer-box a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-footer-merged">
  <div id="contact-banner" class="info-banner">
    <div>HEADER</div>
    <div>SUB-HEADER</div>
    <div>SUB-SUB-HEADER</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-box">
    <h2>
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 'posititon:static' assigned to both '.footer-box' and ''#contact-banner'' elements. The '#contact-banner' element has a bottom position of 30px, so when the '.footer-box' list elements stack it increases the height of that element. Once the height of the '.footer-box' element is greater than 30px, it will overlap the '#contact-banner' element.

To solve this issue I have just remove `position:static` from both of those elements and added it to the '#contact-footer-merged' wrapper.

```css
#contact-footer-merged {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
}
.info-banner {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.info-banner a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info-banner a:hover {
  color: #aaa;
}

.footer-box {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 50;
}

.footer-box h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #A9A9A9;
}

.footer-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #A9A9A9;
}

.footer-box a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-footer-merged">
  <div id="contact-banner" class="info-banner">
    <div>HEADER</div>
    <div>SUB-HEADER</div>
    <div>SUB-SUB-HEADER</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-box">
    <h2>
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a> |
      <a href="/link/">LINK</a>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much for your help!